# Simple Picasa image upload code example

Tags: java, android, picasa

I have done extensive searching but I have found no piece of code that anyone has done showing how to choose an Image from the Android gallery (that's the easy part) and have it uploaded to a default Picasa album (what I need).

Anyone have android java code that can help?

Answer (score 1):

This class seems to do exactly what you need (in particular the run() method): http://code.google.com/p/picasaphotouploader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/android/picasaphotouploader/ImageUploader.java

Comment: It seems that I have to really tailor this code to do what I want, but thanks.. It is the only Example with code that is online...